# Set class path resource

Tags: java, spring, email, thymeleaf

i have a problem width this code:

```html
final Map<String, File> attachments = new HashMap<>();
  final Map<String, String> inlineResources = new HashMap<String, String>();
  inlineResources.put("logo", "/res/img/IN_payoff.png");
  for (File certificateFile : certificates) {
   attachments.put(certificateFile.getName(), certificateFile);
  }
  YadaEmailParam p = new YadaEmailParam();
  
  p.inlineResources = inlineResources;

  yadaEmailService.sendHtmlEmail(p);
 }
```

This error:

```html
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [res/img/IN_payoff.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

How i can set class path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a Maven project, resources that have to be available in the classpath must go in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: No this isn't a Maven project. Its a Java project from GitLab. This html file is template email in src/main/resources, the img is in src/res/img

Answer (score 0):

In case of Maven project, put your resource files in `src/main/resources` directory, as it will end up on classpath and will be automatically included in .jar file. Then your resource will be accessible by `img/IN_payoff.png` path.

Alternatively, you can add your directory to classpath with pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/res</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
 </build>
```

Comment: No this isn't a Maven project. Its a Java project from GitLab. This html file is template email in src/main/resources, the img is in src/res/img